# implementation of quick sort, almost working but not

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

Tried implementing the quick sort algorithm with this piece of code [here](http://ideone.com/9wUcaF)

The code is almost working except one element in the array is not being sorted, I think it must have to do something with the `i,j` used in the `partition` function, not sure..

Am I implementing it correct?

These are the relevant functions :

```
int partition(int a[], int start, int end){
  int i,j,pivot,temp;

  pivot = a[end]; //select last elem as the pivot
  i = start;   // point i and j to before/after start end of the arr
  j= end-1;

  while(true){
    //reduce j until we reach an elem that is less than pivot
    if(a[j] >= pivot){ j= j-1; }    
    //increase i until we reach an elem that is more than pivot
    if(a[i] <= pivot){ i = i+1; }  


    if(i<j){  //swap elems so that it is partitioned
          temp = a[j];
          a[j] = a[i];
          a[i] = temp;
    }
    else{ return j; } //return the boundary for this partition
  }
}

void quick_sort(int arr[], int start, int end){
   int boundary;
   if(start<end){
         boundary = partition(arr,start,end);

         quick_sort(arr,start,boundary);
         quick_sort(arr,boundary+1, end);
   }
   return;
}
```

The initial call is :  `quick_sort(a,0,n);` where `a` is an array of length `n`

This is the algo I'm trying to follow : (`p` and `r` are start and end indexes)

```
Partition(A,p,r)
    x <- A[p]
    i <- p-1
    j <- r+1
    while (True) {
        repeat
            j <- j-1
        until (A[j] <= x)
        repeat
            i <- i+1
        until (A[i] >= x)
        if (i <j) 
           exchange A[i] <- A[j]
        else 
            return(j)
    }
}
```

Looked at all of the possible instances where I could go wrong, not able to zero in on the issue.Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Arrays in C++ are normally indexed from 0 rather than 1 — is the fact that you're using `quick_sort(a, 1, n)` a factor, therefore?

Comment: Usually in C-like languages an array of length _n_ starts with element 0 and ends with element _n_ − 1...

Comment: What is starting `j` value for array length n? Why are you using weird shifted argument values?

Comment: [How to implement classic sorting algorithms in modern C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650626/how-to-implement-classic-sorting-algorithms-in-modern-c).and look at the `Quicksort` section.

Comment: Tried iterating from 0, without any luck. Starting `j` from (n+1)th position of the end of the array so that the comparisons can be made..

Comment: Do you seriously think that array length 4 has a[5] element??

Comment: `n=4 end=4 j=end+1=5  if(a[j]... `

Comment: The part of the pseudo-code where you have `if (i A[j]
        else 
            return(j)` is missing key information.  Your partition algorithm does not represent the two nested `repeat … until` loops in the pseudo-code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes sir, noticed that and updated the question! Thanks for finding that out...Got the algo from the link here- http://www.cc.gatech.edu/classes/cs3158_98_fall/quicksort.html ..which was broken

Answer (score 4):

#### Pass 1

In your (original) partition code, you had:

```
int partition(int a[], int start, int end){
  int i,j,pivot,temp;

  pivot = a[end]; //select last elem as the pivot
  i = start- 1;   // point i and j to before/after start end of the arr
  j= end +1;

  while(true){
    //reduce j until we reach an elem that is less than pivot
    if(a[j] >= pivot){ j= j-1; }    
    //increase i until we reach an elem that is more than pivot
    if(a[i] <= pivot){ i = i+1; }
```

You're only supposed to access `a[start]` to `a[end]`, but you start off with the first iteration of the loop accessing outside theses bounds.  This is bound to be part of the problem.

The fix isn't necessarily so obvious.  It's tempting to just drop the subtraction and addition, but that's not necessarily correct.  One of the key things is getting enough useful diagnostic printing in place to know what's going on.

#### Pass 2

The pseudo-code has been added and fixed since Pass 1.  The pseudo-code is very similar to what's presented at Wikipedia under [QuickSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort).  It is a minor variation on the theme of the 'Hoare Partitioning' — the variation being the use of `repeat … until` in the question versus `do … while` at Wikipedia.

> ```
> algorithm quicksort(A, lo, hi) is
>     if lo < hi then
>         p := partition(A, lo, hi)
>         quicksort(A, lo, p)
>         quicksort(A, p + 1, hi)
>
> algorithm partition(A, lo, hi) is
>     pivot := A[lo]
>     i := lo - 1
>     j := hi + 1
>     loop forever
>         do
>             i := i + 1
>         while A[i] < pivot
>
>         do
>             j := j - 1
>         while A[j] > pivot
>
>         if i >= j then
>             return j
>
>         swap A[i] with A[j]
> ```

Your current version of the partition code is:

```
int partition(int a[], int start, int end){
  int i,j,pivot,temp;

  pivot = a[end]; //select last elem as the pivot
  i = start;   // point i and j to before/after start end of the arr
  j= end-1;

  while(true){
    //reduce j until we reach an elem that is less than pivot
    if(a[j] >= pivot){ j= j-1; }    
    //increase i until we reach an elem that is more than pivot
    if(a[i] <= pivot){ i = i+1; }  

    if(i<j){  //swap elems so that it is partitioned
          temp = a[j];
          a[j] = a[i];
          a[i] = temp;
    }
    else{ return j; } //return the boundary for this partition
  }
}
```

There are a number of key differences:

1. You are using the last element instead of the first as the pivot.
2. You are not looping at all while incrementing `i` and decrementing `j`.

Fixing those problems leads to code like this:

```
static inline void swap_ints(int *A, int i, int j)
{
    int t = A[i];
    A[i] = A[j];
    A[j] = t;
}

static int partition(int a[], int start, int end)
{
    int pivot = a[start];   // select first elem as the pivot
    //printf("-->> P(%d,%d) - pivot %d\n", start, end, pivot);
    int i = start - 1;      // point i before start of the array
    int j = end + 1;        // point j after end of the array

    while (true)
    {
        do
        {
            j--;
            //printf("---- j a[%d] = %d\n", j, a[j]);
        } while (a[j] > pivot);
        do
        {
            i++;
            //printf("---- i a[%d] = %d\n", i, a[i]);
        } while (a[i] < pivot);
        if (i >= j)
            break;
        //printf("-<>- a[%d]=%d, a[%d]=%d\n", j, a[j], i, a[i]);
        swap_ints(a, i, j);
        //printf("-><- a[%d]=%d, a[%d]=%d\n", j, a[j], i, a[i]);
        //dump_data("Post-swap", a, start, end);
    }
    //dump_data("Partition", a, start, end);
    //printf("<<-- P(%d) = %d\n", j, a[j]);
    return j;
}
```

There are lots of commented-out printing functions, which were used at times to reassure me that things were working as intended.

Your main quicksort function was OK, though it got decorated with (lots of) printing too:

```
void quicksort(int arr[], int start, int end)
{
    if (start < end)
    {
        dump_data("QS Pre-partition", arr, start, end);
        int boundary = partition(arr, start, end);
        printf("QS Partition: %d:%d:%d\n", start, boundary, end);
        dump_data("QS Pre-recursion L", arr, start, boundary);
        quicksort(arr, start, boundary);
        dump_data("QS Pre-recursion H", arr, boundary + 1, end);
        quicksort(arr, boundary + 1, end);
        dump_data("QS Post-Sort", arr, start, end);
    }
}
```

The `dump_data()` function looks like:

```
void dump_data(const char *tag, int *data, int start, int end)
{
    printf("%s (%d):", tag, end - start + 1);
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d", data[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

And the test code (`main()`) looks like:

```
int main(void)
{
    int data[] =
    {
        /* random -n 20 0 9 | commalist -b '        ' -n 10 */
        //4, 8, 0, 0, 3, 8, 3, 6, 5, 9,
        //6, 8, 3, 6, 5, 5, 0, 8, 1, 1,
        //3, 9, 4, 7, 2, 6, 9, 0, 6, 1,
        //8, 0, 2, 1, 4, 0, 6, 5, 4, 2,
        //7, 6, 2, 5, 4, 4, 6, 0, 8, 3,
        //6, 1, 2, 7, 4, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4,
        //4, 7, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 9, 6,
        //9, 0, 2, 7, 6, 5, 9, 2, 7, 7,
        9, 7, 0, 9, 5, 4, 8, 7, 9, 9,
        2, 9, 9, 7, 0, 3, 9, 6, 8, 5,
        //5, 1, 4, 5, 5, 4, 0, 2, 6, 1,
        //5, 8, 1, 0, 1, 9, 8, 4, 8, 0,
    };
    enum { NUM_DATA = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]) };

    int data_copy[NUM_DATA];
    for (int end = 1; end < NUM_DATA; end++)
    {
        memcpy(data_copy, data, NUM_DATA * sizeof(data[0]));
        dump_data("Unsorted", data_copy, 0, end);
        quicksort(data_copy, 0, end);
        dump_data("PostSort", data_copy, 0, end);
        check_sorted(data_copy, 0, end);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The `check_sorted()` function doesn't usually say anything (but it did when used on unsorted data):

```
void check_sorted(int *data, int lo, int hi)
{
    for (int i = lo + 1; i < hi; i++)
    {
        if (data[i-1] > data[i])
            printf("Inversion @ A[%d] = %d vs A[%d] = %d\n", i-1, data[i-1], i, data[i]);
    }
}
```

There are various sets of 20 random numbers in the range 0..9 in the `main()` program.

---

Careful re-reading<sup>for the N<sup>th</sup> time</sup> of the Wikipedia page shows:

> *Partitioning:* reorder the array so that all elements with values less than the pivot come before the pivot, while all elements with values greater than the pivot come after it (equal values can go either way).

A previous version of this tail-end commentary was concerned about a pivot value sometimes appearing in the lower half of the partition data, but noted that the sort worked anyway.  The quotation shows that is perfectly permissible — there isn't a problem.  There are partitioning schemes, such as *fat pivot* schemes, where that would not be true.